# Access to my PC

Tags: windows, email

First things first I want to clarify that I'm not trying to do anything suspicious. So my gf has this video on her computer of us on a vacation and I want to get into her computer without her knowing so I can use it as part of  a marriage proposal video to lead up to the real thing. I don't know her passwords at all. I understand there are ways (BTW she has a windows PC), to simply delete the password or change it. However I obviously don't want to do any of that as I'm trying very hard to keep it on the DL from her. It'd be pretty obvious if her PIN was removed and/or changed. I'm hoping to just get in real quick send myself the video through email and delete it off her email.
If this post doesn't follow the guidelines I understand just desperate

Comment: There is no way to access the computer without changing the password to her account and once you do that she obviously will know something is wrong.

Comment: Fwiw this is such a bad idea. If someone did this to my computer, I'd consider this not only a red flag and definitely not accept the proposal, I'd not continue dating them. Boundaries + communication.

Comment: Go the social engineering route. Ask a friend if they can ask her to send that video to them, so they can send it to you.

Comment: Helping you would be against the [Acceptable Use Policy - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy)

Answer (score 1):

If it were trivial to circumvent security on PCs that would be very, very bad. Be grateful you can't just do this, in other words.

You need to have an account on the computer, and that account has access to the file, otherwise you're out of luck.

The last version of Windows you could easily and reliably clear local account passwords on was Windows 7.

You should look for a non-technical solution to this problem.

Comment: Technically speaking, if there's no bitlocker active, you can do it in windows 10 and 11 too. But with Bitlocker active, yeah, no chance, unless you already have access to the pc with an account.